# Invalid left-hand side in assignment when i want to assign variable JS

Tags: javascript

My class attack in `creature.js` return error `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` when I want to change current Hp of a damaged creature. `AttackTest.js` is a unit test when I want to check the current hp of a damaged unit. How can I fix this error?

creature.js

```
import CreatureStatistics from './creatureStatistics.js'

export default class Creature {
    constructor(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange) {
        this.stats = new CreatureStatistics(
            (_name || 'Smok'),
            (_attack || 1),
            (_armor || 1),
            (_maxHp || 10),
            (_moveRange || 100))
        this.currentHp = this.stats.getMaxHp();
    }
    attack(_defender, _attacker) {
        _defender.stats.getMaxHp() = _defender.stats.getMaxHp() - _attacker.stats.getAttack() + _defender.stats.getArmor() //<= Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    }
    getCurrentHp() {
        return this.currentHp
    }
}
```

attackTest.js

```
import Creature from '../creature.js';

export default class AttackTest {
    creatureShouldLost10HpWhenAttackerHas20AttackAndDefenderHas10Armor() {
        let attacker = new Creature('Attack', 20, 5, 110, 5);
        let defender = new Creature('Defender', 5, 10, 100, 5);

        attacker.attack(defender, attacker)
        if (defender.getCurrentHp() !== 10) {
            throw 'Exception: => Creature nie zadala poprawnie obrazen'
        }
    }
}
```

creatureStatistic.js

```
export default class CreatureStatistics {
    constructor(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange) {
        this.name = _name;
        this.attack = _attack;
        this.armor = _armor;
        this.maxHp = _maxHp;
        this.moveRange = _moveRange;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name
    }
    getAttack() {
        return this.attack
    }
    getArmor() {
        return this.armor
    }
    getMaxHp() {
        return this.maxHp
    }
    getMoveRange() {
        return this.moveRange
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign to the result of a function/method call. You either need to use the property itself `.maxHp = 42` or make a setter for it `.setMaxHp(42)`

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line:

```
_defender.stats.getMaxHp() = _defender.stats.getMaxHp() - _attacker.stats.getAttack() + _defender.stats.getArmor() //<= Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

You probably want to change it into:

```
this.currentHp = _defender.stats.getMaxHp() - _attacker.stats.getAttack() + _defender.stats.getArmor()
```

Comment: now function return `attacker.attack(defender, attacker) undefined
attackTest.js:10 defender.getCurrentHp ƒ getCurrentHp() {
        return this.currentHp
    }`

Comment: What would you expect it to return?

Comment: After start `attack` creature needs to lose some Hp his based Hp is 100 and after this i want to check how much he has a Hp after attack  

`getCurrentHp() {
 return this.currentHp
}`

`if (defender.getCurrentHp() !== 90) {
 throw 'Exception: => Creature nie zadala poprawnie obrazen'
}` I need save his Hp after attack and and this.currentHp is for this